# Landscape environment in R Code Chunk in R Markdown breaks plot print

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pander

I have a code chunk in an R Markdown file, that generates multiple `ggplots` in a for loop. The chunk (pseudo-code) is called like so:

````
```{r print_data, results='asis'}
print.all.results()
```
````

Inside the `print.all.results()`, the `ggplots` are generated and printed using standard `print(plot)` (see below).
This works without any problems (HTML as well as PDF).

For the PDF outputs, I would now like to switch to landscape mode using `\usepackage{pdflscape}` (already added to the preamble).

I then tried to switch to the `landscape` environment in the R code within the chunk. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47463861/how-to-use-latex-code-in-r-chunk-in-r-markdown) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414027/how-to-create-r-markdown-sections-inside-a-r-code-chunk-with-proper-code-displa?rq=1), I added the following lines within the `print.all.results()` function:

```
cat("\\begin{landscape}")

for (index in vector) {
    plot <- generateplot()
    print(plot)
}

cat("\\end{landscape}")
```

However, as soon as I do this, the knitting of the document fails. In the intermediary `.tex` file, the graphics are not called via `\includegraphics` anymore but rather, they are linked via the `markdown` call to them (which of course fails in a `tex` compile):

```
\begin{landscape}

![](rmddocument_files/figure-latex/print_data-1.pdf)<!-- --> 

![](rmddocument_files/figure-latex/print_data-2.pdf)<!-- --> 

![](rmddocument_files/figure-latex/print_data-3.pdf)<!-- -->

\end{landscape}
```

I have also tried multiple variations using `pander` but did not find a working solution.

I am now confused why a) the inclusion of the environment suddenly changes the behavior of the `print` for the plot and b) something comparable seems to work in [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414027/how-to-create-r-markdown-sections-inside-a-r-code-chunk-with-proper-code-displa?rq=1).

Is this a bug? Could this be a problem with my build pipeline? What could be a solution?

**NB: I can't generate the `latex` code in the `.rmd` - it has to happen within the code chunk.**

An MWE would be this (easiest run trough Knit Button in R Studio; the `.tex` files and pdfs from the plot are generated in the same folder):

````
---
title: "Landscape Problem"
author: "Dom42"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    extra_dependencies: pdflscape
    keep_tex: yes
---

```{r function}
print.plots.landscape <- function() {
  cat("\\begin{landscape}")
  
  for (i in 1:3) {
    temp.plot <- plot(hist(mtcars[,i]))
    
    print(temp.plot)
  }
  
  cat("\\end{landscape}")
}
```

```{r call, results='asis'}
print.plots.landscape()
```
````

This Example produces a `.tex` that contains

```
\begin{landscape}![](landscape-example_files/figure-latex/call-1.pdf)<!-- --> NULL
![](landscape-example_files/figure-latex/call-2.pdf)<!-- --> NULL
![](landscape-example_files/figure-latex/call-3.pdf)<!-- --> NULL
\end{landscape}
```

However, what should actually come out of it (works, if uncommenting the `cat`s in the `for`-loop):

```
\includegraphics{landscape-example_files/figure-latex/call-1.pdf} NULL
\includegraphics{landscape-example_files/figure-latex/call-2.pdf} NULL
\includegraphics{landscape-example_files/figure-latex/call-3.pdf} NULL
```

If these three calls would now be enclosed in a `landscape` environment, I would be happy and my problem would be solved.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick, indeed you are correct. I'm sorry, but I did not have the time earlier to add it. A base snippet is now added. I think input/output and what the error is, is also clear from the question. If I have the time later on, I can also add that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting the simple markdown syntax for image insertion after including the `landscape` environment is because [`pandoc`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) (the underlying document converter of `r-markdown`) [does not parse the content of latex environments](https://groups.google.com/g/pandoc-discuss/c/oZETB5Ii1Cw).

To add more details, when you click the `knit` button of Rstudio, the `{knitr}` package generates a markdown file containing the markdown syntax for image which as below,

```
\begin{landscape}
![](landscape-example_files/figure-latex/call-1.pdf)<!-- --> NULL
![](landscape-example_files/figure-latex/call-2.pdf)<!-- --> NULL
![](landscape-example_files/figure-latex/call-3.pdf)<!-- --> NULL
\end{landscape}
```

And then `pandoc` is supposed to convert the markdown syntax into latex commands (i.e. `\includegraphics`), But since `pandoc` sees the latex environment `\begin{landscape}`, it doesn't do the conversion and keeps them as is.

So to solve it, we can use the `\landscape ... \endlandscape` command instead of latex environment (thanks to the informative comment by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz)

````
---
title: "Landscape Problem"
author: "Dom42"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: yes
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{pdflscape}
---

```{r function}
print.plots.landscape <- function() {
  cat("\\landscape\n")
  
  for (i in 1:3) {
    temp.plot <- plot(hist(mtcars[,i]))
    
    print(temp.plot)
  }
  
  cat("\n\\endlandscape\n")
}
```

```{r call, results='asis'}
print.plots.landscape()
```
````

Comment: You don't need to define new commands, you can directly use the underlaying commands with which the environment is defined `\landscape ... \endlandscape`

Comment: Great solution! This works! Kudos for tracking down that Google Groups discussion from ten years ago. I was suspecting something like this but did not find any mention in the documentation for either rmarkdown or pandoc (but obviously I was just not looking enough ;))